# Select between with null intervals

Tags: postgresql

I want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at BETWEEN A AND B
```

And these variables can be null, if that is null I wish I could fallback to the lower and upper bound on the data, what I mean:

| Name | Created_at |
| --- | --- |
| First | 01-01-2021 |
| Second | 02-03-2021 |
| Second | 31-12-2021 |

A would be 01-01-2021 and B 31-12-2021, or something that has the same meaning. How can I do that?

Comment: What can be NULL? `created_at`, `A`, `B`? Also, `I wish I could fallback to the lower and upper bound on the data` does not clarify your objective for me.

Comment: A, B can be null (which are the values of created_at. Lower values would be the oldest time, and the earliest one.

Comment: I see English words, but I can't make sense of your sentences. Please [edit] the question to clarify table definition, Postgres version and your objective.

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of `coalesce`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE created_at BETWEEN coalesce(
                            CAST (A AS timestamp with time zone),
                            '-infinity'
                         )
                     AND coalesce(
                            CAST (B AS timestamp with time zone),
                            'infinity'
                         );
```

Comment: i get: `ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone >= text
  Tip: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Well, you didn't tell us the data type of A and B. Add a cast, as in my modified answer.

Comment: Given the amount of data i have, like, a lot... it seems to be timing out, is there another optimum way to do this?

Comment: Then create an appropriate index. You didn't share the actual query or the table definition.

Comment: Yeah, i created an index and didn't help. The average amount is 1M+ of data here

Comment: Either you created the wrong index, or the condition is not selective enough. Add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to your question.